# Certification IDs are different

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

[image]

That "Signing Certificate" X6N2252AB8 is different from my website.[image]

Frist one is from my Xcode and the second is from my Apple development website.
why is it different?
This cause error in "fastlane gym" command...
plz helpme !!

Answer (score 1):

- Kyo Heo - YDBB8774WP is your **Team ID** that you can see on Apple Developer Portal if you go into Account/Membership
- Kyo Heo - X6N2252AB8 is your **Apple Developer Certificate ID**, it's quite normal that it has another identifier, there is no problem with it.
- Your **Apple Distribution Certificate ID** is a third ID which is completely different from the others and so on...

Please include the Fastlane `gym` error output to the your question.